# Error while trying to assign output of a command to shell variable in SunOS

Tags: shell-script, solaris

I am new to shell scripting and solaris operating systems. I want to write a script that monitors disk usage. Following some tutorials online I got started with it. As a first step I tried to assign the output of a command to a variable and echo it.

```
#!/bin/sh

CURRENT=$(df -h /ccviews1|sed -n '2p'|awk '{print $5 }'|sed 's/%//g')
echo $CURRENT
```

When I run the script, it is giving below error

> ./diskMonitor.sh: syntax error at line 3: `CURRENT=$' unexpected

Please help me with this issue. Also, I would like to if writing shell scripts in Ubuntu and writing in Solaris are same. If there is any difference, how should I proceed?

Comment: What version of Solaris are you using? Earlier versions of Solaris have `/bin/sh` as the Bourne Shell.

Comment: Try `#!/bin/bash` instead.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not Bash.  GNU/Linux conflates the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Solaris 10 and older, you need to adjust your script one of these ways:

Portable to the legacy Bourne shell:

```
CURRENT=`df -h /ccviews1|sed -n '2p'|awk '{print $5 }'|sed 's/%//g'`
echo $CURRENT
```

Use a POSIX shell

```
#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh
PATH=$(getconf PATH):$PATH
CURRENT=$(df -h /ccviews1|sed -n '2p'|awk '{print $5 }'|sed 's/%//g')
echo $CURRENT
```

Use Solaris mainstream shell (`bash` will work too here)

```
#!/bin/ksh

CURRENT=$(df -h /ccviews1|sed -n '2p'|nawk '{print $5 }'|sed 's/%//g')
echo $CURRENT
```